# Application is rejected with 14.3 review guideline

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am developing a social app and the app is rejected 5 times with:

> 14.3: Apps that display user generated content must include a method for filtering objectionable material, a mechanism for users to flag offensive content, and the ability to block abusive users from the service
>   ----- 14.3 -----
>
> Your app enables the display of user-generated content but still does not have the recommended precautions in place, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Specifically, it would be appropriate to implement a flagging/reporting button for each individual image that can be uploaded within the app so that users have the opportunity to report any objectionable content.

There is already a mechanism in our app in which we can set a flag for reporting any kind of inappropriate posts (Audio, Video, Image and News) and users. Only logged in users' post doesn't have an option for reporting inappropriateness because users cannot report his/her own post. There is also an option of blocking the user in our app. So please let me know which kind of flagging system Apple want in our app.

Comment: Use this text when applying for rejection.

Comment: would it not be easier to ask the Apple directly? they'd know better what kind of solution they can accept...

Comment: Did you resolve the problem?

Comment: yes as per @shmidt suggestion

Comment: Had you resubmitted the app after rejection or only waited for their reply?

Comment: i  waited for replay  and after 1 day my app was live

Comment: Do you need to prevent them from posting the objectional content as well? Or it's okay to simply flag it after the post being published?

Comment: @KesongXie just put flag or block user Functionality so other user can notify Admin about inappropriate content and its up to Admin take action or not